# Is $A^{-\infty}$ a $Q$-algebra?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, cv.complex-variables

Let $\mathbb{D}=\{z\in \mathbb{C}: |z|<1\}$ and
$$
A^{-\infty}=\Big\{f:\mathbb{D}\rightarrow \mathbb{C}\;|\; \exists n\in \mathbb{N} \textrm{ such that }\|f\|_{-n}= \sup\limits_{z\in \mathbb{D}}\;\!(1-|z|)^n |f(z)| <\infty\Big\}.
$$
$A^{-\infty}$ forms an algebra with pointwise addition and multiplication.

Let the vector space $A^{-\infty}$ be given a topology, by defining the following collection of sets as open neighborhoods of zero:
$$
V(\{n_1,n_2,n_3,\dots\}, \{r_1,r_2,r_3,\dots\})
=
\bigcup_{k=1}^\infty \{f: \|f\|_{-n_k}<r_k\},
$$
where $n_1<n_2<n_3<\dots$ are natural numbers, and $r_k>0$ for each $k$.

**Question** Is $A^{-\infty}$ a $Q$-algebra, that is, is the set of invertibles in $A^{-\infty}$ an open set in $A^{-\infty}$?

Comment: Are you sure that this topology makes addition and multiplcation continuous? It smells like a colimit (=inductive limit) in the category of topological spaces and not in the category of, e.g., locally convex spaces.

Comment: @Jochen Yes, that $A^{-\infty}$ is a topological algebra is known and appears on page 189 of the paper by B. Korenblum (An extension of the Nevanlinna theory. Acta Math., vol.135, 1975).